Having the same _tkinter.TckError with no solution
class AutoCompleteEntry(CTkEntry):
    def __init__(self, master, suggestions, placeholder=None, **kwargs):
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        super().__init__(master, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)
        self.suggestions = suggestions
        self.placeholder = placeholder

        if self.placeholder:
            self.insert_placeholder()

        self.var.trace_add('write', self.changed)
        self.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
        self.bind("<Up>", self.move_up)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.move_down)
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)

        self.lb_up = False
        self.lb_frame = None
        self.lb = None
        self.listbox_destroyed = False

    def insert_placeholder(self):
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self.configure(fg_color="#242424")

    def remove_placeholder(self):
        current_text = self.get()
        if current_text == self.placeholder:
            self.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.configure(fg_color="#242424")

    def on_focus_in(self, event):
        if self.get() == self.placeholder:
            self.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.configure(fg_color="#242424")

    def on_focus_out(self, event):
        if not self.get():
            self.insert_placeholder()

    def changed(self, *args):
        if self.var.get() == '' or self.listbox_destroyed:
            if self.lb_up:
                self.destroy_listbox()
        else:
            words = self.comparison()
            if words:
                if not self.lb_up:
                    self.lb_frame = CTkFrame(self.master)
                    self.lb = ctl.CTkListbox(self.lb_frame,
                                            width=400,
                                            border_width=0,
                                            fg_color="#242424",
                                            font=("Satoshi-Regular", 20),
                                            text_color="#F3F3F3",
                                            bg_color="#111111",
                                            hover_color="#373737",
                                            command=self.show_value)
                    self.lb.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.bind("<Return>", self.selection)
                    self.lb.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
                    self.lb_frame.place(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y() + self.winfo_height())
                    self.lb_up = True
                if self.lb and self.lb.winfo_exists():
                    self.lb.delete(0, tk.END)
                    for w in words:
                        self.lb.insert(tk.END, w)
            else:
                self.destroy_listbox()

    def destroy_listbox(self):
        if self.lb_up:
            if self.lb and self.lb.winfo_exists():
                self.lb.destroy()
                self.lb = None  # Set to None after destruction
            if self.lb_frame and self.lb_frame.winfo_exists():
                self.lb_frame.destroy()
                self.lb_frame = None  # Set to None after destruction
            self.lb_up = False
            self.listbox_destroyed = True

    def selection(self, event):
        if self.lb_up and self.lb and self.lb.winfo_exists():
            try:
                self.var.set(self.lb.get(tk.ACTIVE))
            except tk.TclError:
                return
            self.destroy_listbox()
            self.icursor(tk.END)

    def move_up(self, event):
        if self.lb_up and self.lb and self.lb.winfo_exists():
            try:
                if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                    index = '0'
                else:
                    index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
                if index != '0':
                    self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                    index = str(int(index) - 1)
                    self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                    self.lb.activate(index)
            except tk.TclError:
                return

    def move_down(self, event):
        if self.lb_up and self.lb and self.lb.winfo_exists():
            try:
                if self.lb.curselection() == ():
                    index = '-1'
                else:
                    index = self.lb.curselection()[0]
                if index != tk.END:
                    self.lb.selection_clear(first=index)
                    index = str(int(index) + 1)
                    self.lb.selection_set(first=index)
                    self.lb.activate(index)
            except tk.TclError:
                return

    def comparison(self):
        if self.listbox_destroyed:
            return []
        pattern = self.var.get()
        return [w for w in self.suggestions if w.lower().startswith(pattern.lower())]

    def show_value(self, selected_option):
        movie_update(selected_option)

    def destroy_widget(self):
        self.destroy_listbox()
        self.destroy()


global movie_update
    def movie_update(name):
        movie = name
        search.destroy_widget()  # This should safely destroy the widget
        video1.release()
        video2.release()
        landingcanvas.destroy()

I was trying to make a autofilling search bar which destroys itself when an option is selected from the a list
This code is producing the following error:Exception in Tkinter callback
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!ctkcanvas.!ctkframe2.!ctkframe.!canvas.!ctklistbox"
I cannot find what's the cause of this everything else is doing it's intended job...

Can you [edit] your post to include a traceback? That'll help identify where and why the error is occurring.

Fix the indentation of the shown code.

This code defines a class and some functions, but where are they actually called?  What exact command do you use to run this code?

Please show the full traceback. My guess is that it’s @ bug in customtkinter. That library is a little loose with how it binds events on widgets. It’s probably a binding that fires after you delete the listbox.

It's particularly likely to be a problem with a <Destroy> event handler on a toplevel picking up a child, but destroying a widget when there are already events queues for it can be surprising too. Postponing an actual destroy until idle can help.
